# Using GitHub Actions to deploy Sphinx documentation

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages, python-sphinx, github-pages-deploy-action

I am working on publishing some Sphinx documentation on Github pages using GitHub Actions.

Initially, I followed the [Sphinx documentation generation tutorial](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/tutorial/index.html) to create my documentation files locally. Once I did this successfully, I got to the part of the tutorial for [Deploying a Sphinx project online](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/tutorial/deploying.html). Here is where I am a bit stuck. I am trying to use GitHub pages to display the HTML files for this project but am getting some errors.

To my understanding, in order to do this, I need to use GitHub Actions in order to build the Sphinx documentation so that the `.rst` files can be turned into `HTML` files and then these files can be deployed to the GitHub Pages site.

What I did first: I followed this portion of the tutorial and did three things:

1. Activated GitHub Pages on the repo online
2. Add a `sphinx.yml` file inside of a `.github/workflows` directory I created in the repo online
3. Added a `requirments.txt` files in the `/docs` subdirectory

According to the tutorial online, this is the contents of my `sphinx.yml` file online:

```
name: Sphinx build

on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Build HTML
      uses: ammaraskar/sphinx-action@master

    - name: Upload artifacts
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: html-docs
        path: docs/build/html/

    - name: Deploy
      uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
      if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
      with:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        publish_dir: docs/build/html
```

The content of my `requirements.txt` file:

```
furo==2021.11.16
nbsphinx
sphinx_gallery
sphinx_rtd_theme
markupsafe==2.0.1
geostates
geopandas
pandas
jinja2>=3.0
```

The directory structure for my project online for the GitHub repo is the following:

```
.github/workflows
    sphinx.yml

docs
    _staic
    build
    examples
    source
    all the .rst files
    requirements.txt

project
    all the python files .py

README.md
```

My project and the repo are [available here](https://github.com/eolesinski/doctesting).

The problem is that every time I run the GitHub Actions the build/deploy step fail and the HTML files are not generated and not deployed to the GitHub Pages site. Consequently, when I click the link to the GitHub Pages page it results in a:

```
404 Error Page Not Found
```

The error for the build failure is pretty complex but is shown on the repo page under the Actions tab. I was wondering if anyone had any insight into what the problem is here or what might be happening. I think it might have something to do with the dependencies or perhaps the `demo.yml` file provided in the tutorial does not work correctly. A few causes might be that my project documentation is generated using an additional layer of complexity including using the `autosummary` and the `nbsphinx` packages.

**EDIT 8/30/22:**

Update: So following the excellent suggestion of Steve below, I have applied an iterative approach to installing each missing dependency by adding it to the `requirements.txt` file to slowly remove each of the subsequent errors. The thing that I am running into now is the following error:

```
Notebook error:
182
PandocMissing in examples/Admissions Data.ipynb:
183
Pandoc wasn't found.
184
Please check that pandoc is installed:
185
https://pandoc.org/installing.html
```

Which seems to be arising due to a mismatch with trying to convert one of my `.ipynb` files to markdown to render for the HTML files. After reading extensively [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62398231/building-docs-fails-due-to-missing-pandoc) it seems like there is some issue with using `pip` to install it.

I have read that pandocs requires something in the format of:

```
name: Simple Usage

on: push

jobs:
  convert_via_pandoc:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - uses: docker://pandoc/core:2.9
        with:
          args: "--help" # gets appended to pandoc command
```

Do I just add this to my `sphinx.yml` file somewhere? If so where should this be put in and should all of the code be included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error:

https://github.com/eolesinski/doctesting/runs/8076250971?check_suite_focus=true#step:4:64

> `Could not import extension nbsphinx (exception: No module named 'nbsphinx')`

...means that you need to install the `nbsphinx` extension, and possibly other packages that you already installed in your local environment but did not tell GitHub Actions to also install. To remedy this, add the following to your `requirements.txt`:

```
nbsphinx
```

If you see similar errors again, then add the missing module to `requirements.txt`, and try again. Repeat as necessary.

Pandoc is a system requirement that cannot be installed via `pip`. For installing in GitHub Actions see https://pandoc.org/installing#github-actions.

Comment: Pandoc is a system requirement that cannot be installed via `pip`. For installing in GitHub Actions see https://pandoc.org/installing#github-actions. I have edited my answer to include this step.

Comment: I would change the image to `docker://pandoc/core:2.17.1.1` or whatever is more recent than the 2-year old image you selected. Next determine what commands you actually need to pass to pandoc. I do not know what those are for your project. Those commands would go into an `args:` stanza, per https://github.com/pandoc/pandoc-action-example.

Comment: It seems like everything except pandoc works. There is a separate question for the pandoc problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73544397/407651.

Comment: @StevePiercy Thank you again for taking the time to respond. Yes, I have the example code posted at the bottom of my question. This is my first time using GitHub Actions so which commands and where to put this code is what I am confused about.

Comment: @Ethan: I think you should simply accept this answer. The question was not originally about pandoc.

Comment: @StevePiercy do you have any advice on where I might be able to find out how to do this/learn about this? The documentation imo is not very friendly for beginners.

Comment: I would contact the authors of this through their recommend support channel.